# Is there YYYYWW Format in java

Tags: java, date

Is there any way to use Date in Java with the format YYYYWW? There is week of month but is there any way to find week of the year?

Comment: Yeah there is a week format available according to [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: [Is it what you are looking for?](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20find%20week%20of%20the%20year)

Comment: w Week in year Number 27 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I think _week of month_ will be no use rather use week of year.

Comment: thanks @Ali Gajani. I detailed it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Standard Format

The [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines such week-of-year. You may want to review the Wikipedia articles [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) for guidance, as your format is not quite standard and is ambiguous. The standard uses a `W` and optionally a hyphen, such as `YYYY-Www`.

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) has good support for ISO 8601 including weeks. See the [`ISODateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) class and its [`weekYearWeek`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#weekyearWeek()) method amongst others.

Note that **time zone is crucial** in determining a date and therefore a week. At the stroke of midnight ending Sunday in Paris means a new week in France while still "last week" in Montréal.

Example code using Joda-Time 2.5.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
String output = ISODateTimeFormat.weekyearWeek().print( now );
int weekNumber = now.getWeekOfWeekyear();
```

When run.

```
now: 2014-11-03T02:30:10.124-05:00
output: 2014-W45
```

## Avoid j.u.Date

The java.util.Date and .Calendar and SimpleDateFormat classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either Joda-Time or the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

Answer (score 5):

I am not quite sure about your question, but maybe you want a ISO-like week-date with year and week-of-year. If so then pay attention to the fact that there is another definition of a year, namely a year of weekdate (or other call it week-based-year). This year is in most cases the same as the standard calendar year but can differ at the begin or end of the calendar year dependent on the ISO-week-rules (monday as first day of week and first week-of-year having at least 4 days in calendar year).

If you look for this week-based-year and the ISO-week-of-year then you should use this expression:

```
// In France ISO-8601-week-rules are valid, so let's use this locale to choose ISO.
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYww", Locale.FRANCE); // big letter Y!
```

Otherwise you can of course just go with the other answer of @BetaRide: "yyyyww".

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format and parse any date string.

The format you are looking for is `"yyyyww"`.

Comment: This is not correct. 'y' gives you absolute year, and 'Y' gives you week year, i.e. the year which the week belongs to. 1. January 2012 may belong to year 2012, but it's part of week 52 of year 2011. So it should be YYYYww  .

Answer (score 2):

Letter `y represent Year` where as be careful with - as `w represents Week in year` and `W represents Week in month`

try

```
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyww");
      System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more date-formats

Answer (score 1):

yes we can use Y for week of the month and y for week of the year.
Ex: `Date d =new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat ft = 
              new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyww");
    System.out.println(ft.format(d));`

can give you the current year and week.