# Get range of Week of Year from 0

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am using following to get week of year
.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatforYearWeek = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyww");
String s = dateFormatforYearWeek.format(date)
```

For Oct 26 this gives me value as 201444. However I want it to get as 201443.
I am not sure how to set week of year as 0.
Is it possible? If not how can i modify it.

Is this the correct way?

```
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormatforYearWeek = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyww");
String s = dateFormatforYearWeek.format(date)
```

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do? Get the US week number which is different from the [ISO week number](http://www.calendar-365.com/week-number.html)...?

Comment: Actually in my db the week starts from 0. So I want to make it consistent.

Comment: See this similar Question, [Is there YYYYWW Format in java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24527611/642706)

Comment: Which kind of DB are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do it the following way then:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatForYear = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat yearWeekFormat    = new SimpleDateFormat("w");
Integer          weekFrom0         = Integer.valueOf(yearWeekFormat.format(date)) - 1;
String           s                 = dateFormatForYear.format(date) + weekFrom0;
```

Answer (score 1):

this post can help you:

[Why dec 31 2010 returns 1 as week of year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608470/why-dec-31-2010-returns-1-as-week-of-year)

Try sthg like this:

```
       Calendar calDe = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

## What Is A Week?

The doc for [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) fails to define what they mean by week. Other sources suggest they intended the standard ISO 8601 definition of week. But then they violate that by defining `calendar.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() == 1` rather than 4, as discussed in [this other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6757009/642706ttp://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

What do you mean by a week of year in your Question?

## ISO 8601

As mentioned above, the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) defines a week of year as beginning on Monday, and where the first week contains the first Thursday of the year.

This standard also defines a string format to represent a week of year: `YYYY-Www` or `YYYYWww`. Note the `W` in the middle. That letter is important as it avoids ambiguity with the [year-month](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) format `YYYY-MM`. I suggest you conform to ISO 8601 if at all possible.

## Zero-Based Week Counting

I've never heard of counting weeks from zero. That makes no sense to me; I suggest avoiding this if at all possible.

If not possible, I suggest you use a date-time library to calculate standard week of year and subtract one. But I'm sure this is a bad road to travel.

## Time Zone

Time zone is crucial in determining a date and therefore a week. At the stroke of midnight ending Sunday in Paris means a new week in France while still "last week" in Montréal.

## Joda-Time

The old date-tim classes in Java are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed: java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, java.text.SimpleDateFormat. Avoid them.

Instead use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the java.time package built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
String output = ISODateTimeFormat.weekyearWeek().print( now );
```

When run.

```
now: 2014-11-03T02:30:10.124-05:00
output: 2014-W45
```

If you must insist on that zero-based week number:

```
int zeroBasedWeekNumber = ( now.getWeekOfWeekyear() - 1 ) ;
```